# How do I create a Provisioning Profile for non-Mac-App-Store distribution?

Tags: xcode, macos, provisioning-profile

I'm trying to create a Developer ID-signed Application for OSX.

If I go to **developer.apple.com > Member Center > Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles > Mac Apps > Provisioning Profiles > Distribution**, and then click on the + icon, it only gives me "Mac App Development" and "Mac App Store" as options for the type of provisioning profile:

[image]

Where is the option for "Developer ID-signed", or "Mac App Distribution", or whatever they call the non-app-store distribution profile?

I'm new to Mac development.  I've purchased the $99 dev account.  I have a "Mac App Distribution" *certificate*, but I can't seem to create a provisioning profile for it.  If I try to continue without it, I get the following error when I attempt to export a Developer ID-signed Application:

[image]

Has anyone run into this before?  How do I fix it?

Comment: If you look in your Keychain, do you see "`Developer ID Application: ________`" (insert your name there) listed in any certificate category?

Comment: Everything is developer signed. "Mac App Store" is the one you use to build your final release and it's signed. "Mac App Developement" is used when you are developing the app, testing. Configure xCode to use the right ones. You can even configure to use "developer" profile while debugging and use "release" profile when you Archive for releasing. Goto: xcode project -> select Target (small icon) -> Build settings -> look for profiles. remember when you change something xCode has some delays downloading the latest profiles. (that's true if you are logged in with xCode [goto pref])

Comment: @MichaelDautermann - I don't see that, but I do see "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: _______".

Comment: @Jaro - I won't be submitting this app to the Mac App Store.  It isn't sandboxed or sandbox-able, so I can't distribute it by that means.  But I do need it to be Developer ID-Signed so that I can avoid the Gate Keeper issues.  Also, I've tried various options under the Build Settings, but nothing seems to help avoid the error I'm getting. Do you know of a specific setting that I should be looking for?

Comment: well then just use Developer profile. If I look on the screenshot it looks like you are not logged in with xCode or you are using account that has not the privilages to download profiles in xCode. Make sure you have all your settings correct and your profile are generated correctly: howto video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xh2nnjttOwo